# Simulating a bicycle going around a circle

Tags: simulation

I want to simulate a bicycle moving around a circle. Instead of graphs and calculations, I want to almost see an actual simulation of this happening. How could I do this?

I tried looking up simulations on Mathematica online. However, I couldn't find resources that would allow me to do so. 
Thanks

Comment: The question, as written, is very broad, and is unlikely to get complete answers. A fitting answer would be just as broad as the question itself. The steps to animate a bicycle: 1. find a 3D model 2. import it into Mathematica 3. use `GeometricTransformation` to transform it into the correct position 4. use ListAnimate/Animate to animate it.

Comment: If you mean a full physical _simulation_ of a bicycle with moving parts (not just an animation), that is highly non-trivial to do in Mathematica, and it is much too general for a single question here.

Comment: It is not even clear why bicycle is not falling. See this Science paper https://science.sciencemag.org/content/332/6027/339.abstract